# Using "this" parameter in Typescript static methods doesn't narrow the type to the current class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

This is best explained using an example. I need to reference the current class in a static method, this works as expected:

```
class Cls {
  static fn<T extends typeof Cls>(
    this: T,
    arg: T extends typeof Cls ? true : false,
  ) {}
}

Cls.fn(true);
Cls.fn(false); // Argument of type 'false' is not assignable to parameter of type 'true'.
```

However, when calling `Cls.fn` from another static method, it doesn't work:

```
class Cls {
  static fn1<T extends typeof Cls>(
    this: T,
    arg: T extends typeof Cls ? true : false,
  ) {}

  static fn2<T extends typeof Cls>(this: T) {
    this.fn1(true); // Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T extends typeof Cls ? true : false'.
  }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCIwN4FgBQ1oQC5iwS2GgDMA7AHgBVoBTADy2pIBMYsBPAB2oHsi4EAfAAo0GDFgAWeCAC5oFADSixYAE4BzOVToNmrTjz7wYAfmhZVAV2rQ5RMAmpL00AJTREAXzTLsuAsQkAEyUNPSMLOYGvPwQwpLSWu4oLuJSEAB0pEIW1q4A3MreqMVAA)

Interestingly, it works if I remove `fn2`'s generic or do `this.fn1<typeof Cls>(true)`. This means the error is related to the type of `this`. I think it has to do with `this` referring to any subclass of `Cls` as opposed to exactly `Cls`. However, even if `this` is a subclass of `Cls`, `T extends typeof Cls` would still be true.

Is this a bug where Typescript uses the wrong value for `this`? If it's not a bug, how can I fix it?

In my actual code, I need to reference the current class because the method accepts different arguments depending on the subclass.

**Edit:** [here's a more realistic example using subclasses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEBC0CmsDexaygFwtgliLAGYB2APACqxIAe2SpAJnNgJ4AOSA9sQsgD4AFBkyxsAC3xQAXLEoAaUZggAnAOZzqdBs1acefAMoBXAEawA-LADkUczdhybZ5DaWYAlGgC%20wP6CQMLCmFjqMLPxQKOiY0qGwALziqiZIANzAojh4hCSkAExC3rFiktIAdGRCLm6emWLiUlBVpDX2Zjb1ogGYOQREZADMVDT0EfpcvCHmwuWy8iXKTZXVtdFdDWXNre0O9bAA9IfyzbBg%20KQo0qQ22LAA7tyqANaX6rDQY1wgDEwVPX8WUQ0V26yQm2AIKQYI6kNCsP2mQRa1cG26QA)

Comment: An unresolved generic type parameter is the reason. If you inspect the inferred type of inner `this.fn` calls, you will see `Base.fn<T>` meaning the `T` is not resolved, whereas the concrete value of `'sub'` implies `T` is definitely `typeof Sub`. This all happens because of the indirection via `T` being also the generic type parameter of the outer `fn3` method as well. For the same reason doing `this.fn<typeof Sub>('sub');` works - as the indirection is removed, and `T` is resolved (and is determined to satisfy the `extends typeof Sub` constraint).

Comment: @OlegValter could you please provide an answer?

Comment: @captain-yossarian thanks, likely later, but I do not have much time on my hands lately... There is still a problem of working around this limitation -  as you know, dancing around unresllved generic type parameters can ge quite a task

Comment: Thanks @OlegValter, I read more about unresolved generics and how they don't work well with conditionals. By removing some conditionals from my code, a lot of errors that I've previously had to ts-ignore went away. Looking forward to your answer if you get to it!

Comment: @LeoJiang NP! Btw, there is actually a workaround for the issue at hand (at least I think so), see the answer I finally got some time to write up. The trick is, as often with generic type parameters, is to move the constraint validation in a conditional type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is explained by an unresolved generic type parameter.

This is caused by an indirection introduced by what is basically a higher-order function (method). In the case of a non-generic method `fn2` (using the `Sub`/`Base` example), the inference works as expected as the type parameter gets resolved to `typeof Sub` in the derived class `Sub`:

```js
Base.fn<typeof Sub>(this: typeof Sub, arg: "sub"): void
```

Unfortunately, in the case of `fn3`, it is itself a generic function (method), leading to the `T` generic parameter in calls to `fn` being unresolved, which can be seen from the inferred signature:

```js
Base.fn<T>(this: T, arg: T extends typeof Sub ? "sub" : "base"): void
```

This clears up what the following compiler error means - as the conditional type is also left unresolved, neither `"sub"` nor `"base"` will be assignable to `T extends typeof Sub ? "sub" : "base"`:

> Argument of type '"sub"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T extends typeof Sub ? "sub" : "base"'

One could, as you rightfully noted, remove the generic type parameter of the higher-order method, thus removing the indirection:

```js
static fn3(this: typeof Sub) {
    this.fn('base'); // error
    this.fn('sub'); // OK
}
```

This, however, presents complications in further derived classes should you ever need `this`:

```js
class Sub {   
    static fn4(this: typeof Sub) {
        this.fn('sub');
        return this;
    } 
}

class SubSub extends Sub {}

SubSub.fn4(); // typeof Sub, probably wanted typeof SubSub
```

There is an alternative, though - do not constrain the `T` parameter and instead constrain the type of `this` based on what `T` is inferred to be. The classic technique is using a conditional type that resolves to itself of `never`:

```js
class Sub extends Base {
  static fn3<T>(this: T extends typeof Sub? T: never) {
    this.fn('base'); // error
    this.fn('sub'); // OK
    return this;
  }
}

Sub.fn('sub'); // OK
Sub.fn('base'); // error
Sub.fn3(); // typeof Sub
```

The signature of the inner `this.fn()` call is inferred as:

```js
Base.fn<T extends typeof Sub ? T : never>(this: T extends typeof Sub ? T : never, arg: (T extends typeof Sub ? T : never) extends typeof Sub ? "sub" : "base"): void
```

By further *deferring* the evaluation via `T extends typeof Sub ? T : never` we actually helped the compiler: now it nows that `T` is guaranteed to be `typeof Sub` by the time of instantiation.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEBC0CmsDexaygFwtgliLAGYB2APACqxIAe2SpAJnNgJ4AOSA9sQsgD4AFBkyxsAC3xQAXLEoAaUZggAnAOZzqdBs1acefAMoBXAEawA-LADkUczdhybZ5DaWYAlGgC%20wP6CQMLCmFjqMLPxQKOiY0qGwALziqiZIANzAojh4hCSkAExC3rFiktIAdGRCLm6emWLiUlBVpDX2Zjb1ogGYOQREZAByVDT0EfpcvCHmwuWylCXKTZXVtdFdDWXNre0O9WI9WX24A-kAzFRzzVpjupHsU8bm1pRypEgAbkiqS43zu3WSE2sAA9KCaKpVNxVMsAWsOiDwbAAPIAaWWqiQ2BMqlIKyg6TBEO04z04gM0wSrycsA%2031hmF6WFOeTIABYhPM5I9DDMzH9tqs2nZ9ltMFicXiCVs-AFENFAa4Nt0FUhAYjusBQhqxcTURidWtlcCDsiftDYUbSOdikTkbyqeYgA)